# Quicksight Row Level Access - Exclude Rule

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-quicksight

Is there a way to use tag based row level access in `quicksight` to exclude values?

If I have a tag called tag_id, and I want to exclude all records with a tag_id of 5.

Is that possible?

I don't want to have to provide all of the tags except the one I want to exclude just to make this work.

[image]